# how to populate date in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In view code:

```
<% @hotels.each do |h|  %>
 <%= h.hotel_Name%><% @hotelName=h.hotel_Name%>
 <%= image_tag h.hotelImage_url,:size=>'160x120'%>
 <%= image_tag('1407945135.png',:size=>'20x20',:alt=>'Logo')%>
 <%= h.hotel_location%>
 <%= link_to("ViewMenu",{:controller=>'menus',:hotel_id=>h.id}, class:'btn-orange')%>
<% end%>
```

In controller:

```
@hotels= Hotel.where('hotel_location LIKE ?',"%#{params[:search]}%")

**@offers=Offer.all**
```

I am new to Rails. I have a page where a user can see all the hotels available for a particular city. I have two tables in database.The first table name is `hotels` where all the information of the hotels is available and another is `offers` where all the offers are available including a `hotel_id`. So, I want to see all the offers in the each block if `id` from `hotels` table equals to `hotel_id` from `offers` table. How do I do that?

I have another issue.The offers table contains startDate and endDate field.I want to see the offer to the user if today's date is in between the two dates or equals to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change query for `@hotels` to this:

```
@hotels= Hotel.includes(:offers).where('hotel_location LIKE ?',"%#{params[:search]}%")
```

Here `includes` eager loads the related offers for a hotel in one single query. [More on includes here.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

Make sure you have this in your *app/models/hotel.rb*:

```
has_many :offers
```

Now, in view. You can simply call offers:

```
<% @hotels.each do |h|  %>
 <%= h.hotel_Name%><% @hotelName=h.hotel_Name%>
 <%= image_tag h.hotelImage_url,:size=>'160x120'%>
 <%= image_tag('1407945135.png',:size=>'20x20',:alt=>'Logo')%>
 <%= h.hotel_location%>
 <% h.offers.each do |offer| %>
    <%= offer.coupon_code %>
 <% end %>
 <%= link_to("ViewMenu",{:controller=>'menus',:hotel_id=>h.id}, class:'btn-orange')%>
<% end%>
```

Comment: another issue is that if i refresh the page all the records from database a user can see, but i want to see hotels for a particular place.It's working before refresh the same page.

Comment: Are you sure about the query? `where('hotel_location LIKE ?',"%#{params[:search]}%")` I am sure that it is because of the where query. Just have look at it once. Perhaps params[:search] is not available?

Comment: yes,params[:search] gets nothing after page gets refreshed...so how do i fix it.

Comment: You're probably not setting value of search in URL. Is it a `POST` call? Try to change it to 'GET' and have `form` value to `params[:search]` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Write this query in controller

```
@hotels= Hotel.where('hotel_location LIKE ?',"%#{params[:search]}%").includes(:offers)
```

And in view you can do

```
@hotels.each do |hotel|
  <%= hotel.hotel_Name%><% @hotelName=hotel.hotel_Name%>
  <%= image_tag hotel.hotelImage_url,:size=>'160x120'%>
  <%= image_tag('1407945135.png',:size=>'20x20',:alt=>'Logo')%>
  <%= hotel.hotel_location%>
  <% hotel.offers.each do |offer| %>
    <%= offer.try(:name) %>
    <%= offer.try(:coupon_code) %>
    # any offer field you want to show, try is used to avoid errors if offer is nil
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Buddy, you forgot to add ERB tags.

Comment: I have another issue.The `offers` table contains startDate and endDate field.I want to see the offer to the user if today's date is in between the two dates.